# How to save decimal heights in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm facing this strange problem while saving numeric values in mongodb.
I'm saving height of people in mongodb as Number, so a person with height of 5'.1" is saved as 5.1 and a person with a height of 5'.10" is also saved as 5.1.

I can't change it to string because I have a my search query based on number, ("height" : {"$gte": req.body.height.minimum_height, "$lte": req.body.height.maximum_height}).

I'm sure there must be a way to save specific values to deal with monetary transactions, but I'm not sure how to do it in my scenario.

Any suggestions are welcome !!

Comment: And what's the problem? Or what is your question? DB store values as they are. You can formate the number in your client app. Or is there something I misunderstood?

Comment: Which version of mongoDB are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Since the height is already a number, it would be better to treat it in metric units and follow the convention that it represents height in centimetres.

When retrieving heights then as @J.F. suggested in the comment it can be formatted in the client app or wherever else it is required.

When storing heights it can be converted to centimetres.

For example `5'10''` becomes `(5 x 12 + 10) x 2.54 = 177.8`

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use two fields: the numeric value and the display value.

For 5' 10", the numeric value is `5 + 10/12` which is 5.83333...

```
irb(main):001:0> 5+(10/12.0)
=> 5.833333333333333
```

Then use the numeric field for searches and calculations and keep `5' 10"` in the display field for rendering to users.

Alternatively you can only store the numeric value and calculate the display value:

```
irb(main):007:0> i = (5.833333333333333 * 12).round; f = i / 12; i = i % 12
=> 10
irb(main):008:0> f
=> 5
irb(main):009:0> i
=> 10
irb(main):010:0> "#{f}' #{i}\""
=> "5' 10\""
irb(main):011:0>
```